# .Net Native IoC container registration issue on Release mode

Tags: c#, uwp, ioc-container, .net-native

Application works as it should be on Debug mode.

On Release mode I am getting exception saying

> Exception thrown: 'Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException' in Autofac.dll
>
> Additional information: The requested service 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[[TIKSN.GroceryChecklist.Models.Configuration.HockeyAppConfiguration, Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

This is the line that throws exception

```
var hockeyAppOptions = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<HockeyAppConfiguration>>();
```

But this option is configured and works fine in Debug mode.

```
services.Configure<HockeyAppConfiguration>(option =>
        {
            option.AppID = "my key";

        });
```

I also tried to add type registration line in *Default.rd.xml* file but it did not work neither.

```
<Type Name="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions{TIKSN.GroceryChecklist.Models.Configuration.HockeyAppConfiguration}" Dynamic="Required Public" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I added this line and run on Debug mode.

```
Debug.WriteLine($"hockeyAppOptions.Type is {hockeyAppOptions.GetType().FullName}");
```

Output were

```
hockeyAppOptions.Type is Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1[[TIKSN.GroceryChecklist.Models.Configuration.HockeyAppConfiguration, Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

So I replaced previous like in RD.XML with

```
<Type Name="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager{TIKSN.GroceryChecklist.Models.Configuration.HockeyAppConfiguration}" Dynamic="Required Public" />
```

And it worked.

Comment: Hello! Very happy to see you're not blocked. Presumably we (the .NET Native compiler) can do a better job here. Alternately, there may be a small edit to Autofac that can give help us do the right analysis. I'll make a note to investigate some options and follow up with Autofac if necessary.